How to address variables dynamically and sequentially? Such as Variable1, Variable2, and so on
Let's say I have 3 separate arrays (which could be combined into a two-dimensional array, but let's say that's not allowed) of equal size.
I want to use a for loop to step through these arrays. We all know the subscript of an array can be referenced dynamically:
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << array1[i];
}

But how can I jump to the next array programmatically/dynamically? I.E. nested for loop.
How can I do something akin to arrayX[i]?
Other than condensing separate variables (or arrays) into arrays, to enable dynamic stepping via the subscript, is there any way to do this?
I've considered the idea of using pointers, but I believe that would have to rely on the assumption that these arrays would be allocated sequentially in memory, using the known memory size of the array as an offset and making calculated jumps. Is this typically the rule with C++ if variables/arrays are declared immediately after each other or in the same line? If not, is there a way to ensure this?
I tried writing the function calls out individually, which is not scalable.

Combining the 3 separate arrays into 1 bidimensional array seems the way to go, as it would let you write array[x][i]. Why can't you do that? Is this a school project, and your teacher doesn't want it?

"I tried writing the function calls out individually, which is not scalable." What function calls? Nothing has been mentioned about functions in the rest of your post. Just wildly guessing: might you be looking for a template function, or perhaps a function that could act on an array?

It is possible to have an array of arrays.   e.g. some_type array2[5][3];   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) cout << array2[i][j];}.    In this, each array2[i] is an array of three elements, and array2[i][j] accesses elements of array2[i].   You need to keep array indices within bounds.

I apologize about the "function calls" portion. Stackoverflow made me fill out a 2nd text field with the prompt of "explain what you've tried and why it will not work". It had a minimum number of characters necessary before allowing me to post, so I tried to keep it somewhat relevant.
It is basically just in reference that, without being able to crank through the arrays programmatically, I must call them individually with repeated function calls, written out manually.

If the arrays are all of the same size you can create an array of pointers to those arrays and then use them like a 2d array.  There is a caveat that since it uses pointers to arrays then you need to dereference the pointer to get the array.  That can look like
int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int arr2[] = {5,6,7,8};
    int arr3[] = {9,10,11,12};
    
    int (*data[3])[4] = {&arr1, &arr2, &arr3};
    //         ^   ^this 4 is for the size of the arrays
    //         |- this 3 is number of pointers to the arrays
    
    for (const auto& row : data)
    {
        for (const auto& elem : *row) // dereference pointer to array to get elements
            std::cout << elem << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

You can see it working in this live example.

In a more modern approach you can have a std::array of std::spans that let you stich the separate arrays into one.  That looks like
int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3};
    int arr2[] = {4,5,6};
    int arr3[] = {7,8,9};
    
    std::array<std::span<int>, 3> data = {std::span{arr1}, std::span{arr2}, std::span{arr3}};
    
    for (const auto& row : data)
    {
        for (const auto& elem : row)
            std::cout << elem << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

and you can see it working in this live example.

Thanks for this. I believe your first example is close to what I was trying to figure out in my head.
I was hoping to grab the memory address of the beginning of the first array, then use known data type sizes to jump along the memory bank. If I understand it correctly, your example does something along these lines, using pointers.

In int (*data[3])[3] I'm afraid you have swapped the explanation of what the different 3s are for. If the arrays had 4 elements, you'd need int (*data[3])[4]. And if you use this example, there's no need to explain which number corresponds to what, as it becomes obvious! :-)

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica Good catch.  Code updated.

@ShaunLove Yes.  The size of an array is part of its type.  That is why an array is not a pointer.  This means you can create a pointer to an array and the size information will be included in that since the size is part of the array type.  This lets it get deduced for us in ranged based for loops and in other things.  The more modern approach is just named wrappers for those types and I find are easier to reason with.
